# Trying to get two actions to have different views, but the same URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with shepherds (i.e. the users) and each shepherd has a set of animals. I am trying to make it so that if the logged in shepherd tries to view one of their animals it takes them to a view controlled by the edit action. Alternatively, if the shepherd tries to view another shepherd's animals it gives them a view controlled by the show action. I'd prefer to not have URLs with `*/edit` - I want them to look the same for edit and show. In my `routes.rb` file I have this...

```
get '/shepherds/:username/:eartag', to: 'animals#show', as: :shepherd_animal_show
get '/shepherds/:username/:eartag', to: 'animals#edit', as: :shepherd_animal_edit
```

In the shepherd's show view I create a link to their animals like this...

```
<% if animal.shepherd == current_shepherd %>
    <a href="<%= shepherd_animal_edit_path(username: animal.shepherd.username, eartag: animal.eartag) %>"
<% else %>
    <a href="<%= shepherd_animal_show_path(username: animal.shepherd.username, eartag: animal.eartag) %>"
<% end %>
```

I can see that when I'm logged in and try to access my animals, it goes into the block with the `shepherd_animal_edit_path`, but it directs me to the show view rather than the edit view. Here's part of the output of the routes...

```
shepherd_animal_show GET    /shepherds/:username/:eartag(.:format)  animals#show
shepherd_animal_edit GET    /shepherds/:username/:eartag(.:format)  animals#edit
```

I'm a bit of a beginner at Rails and would really appreciate any help people can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using the `show` action for both, and just rendering a different template depending on the animal ownership. I.e.:

```
def show
  ...
  render 'edit' if animal.shepherd == current_shepherd
  # the show template will be rendered automatically if `render` wasn't explicitly called
end
```

Then in your view, you can unconditionally link to the show action, and the controller will take care of deciding which view template to render.

Also, FWIW, I would probably define the routes as follows:

```
resources :shepherds, shallow: true do
  resources :animals
end
```

And then use the `link_to` helper in the view instead of hard-coding HTML tags:

```
<%= link_to animal_path(animal) %>
```

But that would then allow you to do other things like:

```
link_to shepherd_animals_path(@shepherd) # link to the `index` action of `AnimalsController`, with `params[:shepherd_id]` set to `@shepherd.id`.
```

That would then allow you to render (or not render) other controls for the shepherd to manage his/her own flock if `current_shepherd.id == params[:shepherd_id]` (or `current_shepherd == Shepherd.find(params[:shepherd_id])`).

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestsions!

Comment: Another quick question... why render rather than redirect?

Comment: @PatS First, because you said "I'd prefer to not have URLs with */edit". :-) But second, because it's unnecessary if the view of a shepherd's own animal(s) is always going to contain the form for editing an animal (i.e. you don't need to have a separate, read-only `show` view of a shepherd's own animal). It's easier and fulfills your requirements to just allow the show action to render the edit template if the shepherd owns the animal being shown. Hope that makes sense!